# Php - how to create floor with exactly 8 decimal digits (x.8y)

Tags: php, mysql

I want to have number with 8 decimal digits but using floor not 4/5 rounding.  For example:

```
1.000000009 -> 1.00000000
1.003000001 -> 1.00300000
111 -> 111.00000000
```

I have tried this line of code:

```
$ammount = floor($ammount*100000000) / 100000000;
```

But for a number like "111" it switched to "1" in mysql with this line:

```
`mysqli_query($connection, "INSERT INTO table VALUES('', '$id', 'name', '$ammount', now(), 'yes', 'no')");`
```

I used this code too but it did 4/5 rounding not floor:

```
$ammount = number_format($ammount, 8);
```

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: `If i putted that number: "111" it switched to "1.00000000"` I don't see that : https://eval.in/820205

Comment: "But i want too number to be round to lower value"

Answer (score 0):

You want 8 decimal digits, but always rounding down instead of using 4/5 rounding.

The fix is simple: subtract 0.000000005 then let the 4/5 rounding happen:

```
$floord = 0.000000005;

$a = 1.000000009;
echo sprintf('%.8f', $a - $floord) . "\r\n";
$a = 1.003000001;
echo sprintf('%.8f', $a - $floord) . "\r\n";
$a = 87654321;
echo sprintf('%.8f', $a - $floord) . "\r\n";
```

The results are:

```
1.00000000
1.00300000
87654321.00000000
```

To be clear, what you supply to MySQL is:

```
$around = sprintf('%.8f', $a - $floord);
```